# transfer associated values from popup to parent window jsp/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, popup

I have a popup window with data in a table from database and I am able to transfer the values from the popup to parent window like this:

popup data:

```
             <%
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    ArrayList one = (ArrayList) all.get(i);
            %>
            <tr style="height:30px; padding:4px;">
                <td><div align="center"><a href="" onclick="getBranchValue(this)" id="cname"><%=(String) one.get(0)%></a></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><%=(String) one.get(1)%></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><%=(String) one.get(2)%></div></td>
            </tr>
            <% }%>
```

getBranchValue javascript:

```
 function getBranchValue(ths) {
                if (window.opener !== null && !window.opener.closed) {
                    var func = window.opener.document.getElementById("solid");
                    func.value = ths.innerHTML; //for innerhtml
                    window.close();
                }

            }
```

I need also to Transfer data in the second array to the parent window so I have Modified by table to:

```
<a href="" onclick="getBranchValue(this,<%=(String) one.get(1)%>)" id="cname">
```

and my function to:

```
function getBranchValue(ths, soldesc) {
                    if (window.opener !== null && !window.opener.closed) {
                        var func =     window.opener.document.getElementById("solid");
var desc = window.opener.document.getElementById("branchname");
func.value = ths.innerHTML; //for innerhtml
    desc.value = soldesc;
                        window.close();
                    }

                }
```

But on click it just hangs in there. What should I do?

Comment: Any javascript errors in browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must edit code like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="getBranchValue(this,'<%=(String) one.get(1)%>')" id="cname">
```

(using single quotation on string parameter that must be passed to JS function)